# Node.js not executing last expression in callback

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I’ve written this code to query a MySQL database in Node 8:

```
const getDB = require('./db');
function getCrawls(cb) {
  const db = getDB();
  const rows = db.query('select * from crawls', (err, result) => {
    console.log('got result', result);
    cb(result);
  });
}
getCrawls(c => console.log('done', c));
```

However, I only get the following output when I run it:

```
got result []
```

Now the strange thing is it works if I add another `console.log` after the callback is called:

```
const getDB = require('./db');
function getCrawls(cb) {
  const db = getDB();
  const rows = db.query('select * from crawls', (err, result) => {
    console.log('got result', result);
    cb(result);
    console.log('complete');
  });
}
getCrawls(c => console.log('done', c));
```

Now I get this output:

```
got result []
done []
```

It seems that the last statement of the query callback isn’t being called, does anybody have any idea why this could be happening?

**Edit:**

Here's the code for getDB

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
function getDB() {
  const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
    user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
    password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.MYSQL_DATABASE,
  })
  db.connect();
  return db;
}
module.exports = getDB;
```

It sounds like the error may be related to the MySQL module?

Answer (score 1):

Using the info we have from your code, it should work fine; looking at the following snippet.

It seems that your code is stuck executing `cb(result);` maybe there is an un-catched exception there?

```js
function query(data, callback) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback(false, ['result']);
  }, 1000);
}

function getCrawls(cb) {
  const rows = query('select * from crawls', (err, result) => {
    console.log('got result', result);
    
    cb(result);
    
    console.log('complete');
  });
}

getCrawls(c => console.log('done', c));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've added my code for getDB to the question. Sounds like the issue may be related to the mysql module?

Comment: Considering the fact you get `got result` I don't think that it's related to the db request

Comment: Try and see if it is connecting successfully to the database: `con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});` Is there any errors in the node console ?

Comment: You can try the examples in this article and tell us what the problem is: https://codeforgeek.com/2015/01/nodejs-mysql-tutorial/